# Timeout error when creating and adding a CordovaWebView programmatically

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to create a CordovaWebView and insert it into the layout for my activity in its onCreate method, like so:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.master_layout);

    webView = new CordovaWebView(this);
    webView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    layout.addView(webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

I'm getting a timeout error from CordovaWebView, and setting the load timeout preference in the XML file doesn't make any difference.
Am I missing something?